Manhwa with a saintess who died and reincarnated into a little girl
I forgot the name of this manhwa I was reading. It starts off with the female lead who is now a little girl and she meets with a man (some kind of priest or something) who was brought by her parents to help her since she would never smile and didn't act like a child or something. The girl then scares the guy off by telling him that she is the saintess who went crazy and killed a bunch of people a long time ago, which immediately scares him off. So basically she was like a saintess who was mind controlled or something then went on a rampage killing a bunch of people before she eventually died (can't remember how) and then reincarnated and became the daughter of a noble (I think she has blonde hair now as well but not sure)
I can't remember much more, but I hope this is enough.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

it's called "Ways to Satisfy a Devil"

Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you [edit] this to explain how it matches the details provided in the question?
